# Regex to get url from HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, regex

I'm using the following Regex (which I found online) to obtain the urls within a HTML page;

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"url\((?<char>['""])?(?<url>.*?)\k<char>?\)");
```

Works fine for the HTML below;

```
<div style="background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;">UK</div>
```

However returns more than I need when the HTML page contained the following Javascript, returning 'destpage'

```
function buildurl(destpage)
```

I tried the following regex to include a colon, but it appears to be invalid

```
:url\((?<char>['""])?(?<:url>.*?)\k<char>?\)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1043380  Stop using Regex for parsing html. Use a more appropriate tool.

Comment: Try using a `\b` (word boundary) instead of a colon.

Comment: @Jerry Adding \b around url seemed to do the trick. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

To get all the URLs, use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead of a Regex. From their example page

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
{

}
```

You can expand on that to obtain your style urls by, for example, using `//@style` to get the `style` nodes and iterating through those to extract the `url` value.

Answer (score 0):

Only add the colon to the front:

```
:url\((?<char>['""])?(?<url>.*?)\k<char>?\)
```

The second "`url`" is the name of that group.